# Does an excitation of any quantum field extend forever through space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

For visualization purposes, let’s say I slam my hand into sheet metal and it vibrates. Will that vibration extend beyond the metal sheet into the space surrounding it, and would that energy wave permeate into space forever? (even if it’s on a very small scale)

The question I’m trying to get at is: does an excitation of quantum fields cause a wave of energy that travels forever?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

For your example of the metal sheet, the wave is vibration of the metal sheet itself, so it doesn't make sense for that to extend beyond the sheet. However the sheet will also cause vibration of the surrounding air, which produces a sound wave. This sound wave can propagate out very far, but not forever, since sound waves damp. Eventually the energy in the sound wave will be converted to random thermal of the air molecules.

There are other waves in nature that experience much less damping than sound waves. If you shine a flashlight up into space on a clear day, I think there's a good chance that some of the emitted photons will still by flying through the universe billions of years from now. There are plenty of photons left over from the Big Bang, see '[cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background).'

Finally, in quantum field theory, well, technically everything is a wave (electrons, protons, atoms, molecules, rocks... though the interpretation gets a bit tricky as the object gets larger). So in that sense, if you just throw the metal sheet out into space, then maybe that would count too!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can happen. The energy of your hand will be transferred to the atoms of the metal sheet. As the atoms vibrate, they interact with the quantum fields and transfer the energy to the fields creating excitations. These excitations mays travel through spacetime. If you look from another perspective, the energy of your hand is travelling in the form of excitations through spacetime.

Note:- I considered that the experiment was carried out in vacuum of space and no other medium was present.